# Allow select SQL query to be execute from stored procedure only

Tags: sql-server

I have a C# project to automate Children Toys storehouse IN/OUT operations. My application uses ADO.NET to communicate with the SQL Server database. I have created a login named "LiBX". I deny all permissions on all my database table and grant `EXECUTE` permissions on all stored procedures but when I run the application an error message appears:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tableMatrials',database 'STORDB',schema 'dbo'

How can I deny all permissions in all database tables and allow SQL query to be executed from stored procedures only?

Comment: Stored procedures take advantage of ownership chaining to provide access to data so that users do not need to have explicit permission to access database objects. An ownership chain exists when objects that access each other sequentially are owned by the same user. For example, a stored procedure can call other stored procedures, or a stored procedure can access multiple tables.

Comment: If all objects in the chain of execution have the same owner, then SQL Server only checks the EXECUTE permission for the caller, not the caller's permissions on other objects. Therefore you need to grant only EXECUTE permissions on stored procedures; you can revoke or deny all permissions on the underlying tables." --MSDN 
it should work ??? but why it's not working for me ?

Comment: Is the stored procedure in the same database as the table?

Comment: yes,it's in the same database

Comment: DENY trumps ALL other permissions including GRANT, might be a good place to start. "DENY blocks access. DENY trumps all other access. If a user has both a GRANT and a DENY on a given object, by whatever means, the DENY will take effect." From http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/

Comment: Also, why use DENY on everything?  When you create a user in SQL server, it, by default, has no permissions until you grant them. So why mess with DENY?  You should be able to just grant that user the appropriate access (db_datareader, db_datawriter, etc) to what it needs and forgot the DENY.

Comment: Another VERY handy role to add would be something like 'db_executor' and grant that role EXECUTE permissions.  That way you can control who can execute SPs.

Comment: in my application I create a multi user system and user permission I check the user permission inside the stored procedure by using username and password as parameter I want to deny every thing in tables for security reason my application should run in network in many pc's  I just want to allow user to call my stored procedure

Comment: I just noticed the problem is inside the stored procedures that use EXECUTE function or sp_executesql system stored procedure but it's working in stored procedure that use normal T-SQL statement " directly not dynamically " without problems can I avoid that ?? and why EXECUTE and sp_executesql cause this problem ??

Comment: If your stored procedure contains ANY data reading, won't they need GRANT access on SELECT as well?

Comment: I have 3 stored procedure the first use normal T-SQL statement like "select * from xxx " the second use dynamic sql like "declare @x nvarchar(30) set @x = 'select * form xxx' EXECUTE(@x)" and the third use dynamic sql as well, the first one executed without problem but the second and third cause the error message to appear I want to know why this happen ? and how can I avoid this problem without altering the second and third stored procedure's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a stored procedure, the queries execute in the context of the caller, but can be set to run as the Owner instead, giving a higher level of permission - use `EXECUTE AS OWNER`. This can be a useful way to circumvent situations that aren't completely covered by ownership chaining.

Comment: thanks Mr.Rob Could you please tell me how can I do that for dynamic SQL.
.
EXECUTE AS owner EXECUTE (@QR) 
Incorrect syntax near 'owner'.

Comment: No, you do it in the stored procedure from which you call sp_executesql.

Comment: I have Two stored procedures and the both use Dynamic SQL
In the first one I use EXECUTE function and in the second one I use the system stored procedure sp_execute sql I try in that stored procedure to use EXECUTE AS OWNER like this :
"execute as owner exec sp_executesql @QueryString,N'@id int output',@IDX output"
It's showing the error message 
"Incorrect syntax near 'owner'." thank you Mr.Rob for your help

Comment: No, you use WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER in the CREATE part of the stored proc. Like: `CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc(@i int) WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS BEGIN ... END`

Comment: it's my wrong yes you are right it's working now thank you Mr.Rob